# How to hold a port open without a live PID

Tags: linux, linux-networking, socket

I have some iptables port-forwards and I want to make SURE that no other process on the system uses those ports.  I can bind() a socket myself, so other processes get EADDRINUSE, but if my process dies those sockets become available for use again and I can lose the race.

For example:

- I set a port-forward on port 8000 to some other destination
- other process tries to bind() to 8000
- other process should fail

In the other order:

- other process binds() to 8000
- I try to set a port-forward on port 8000
- I fail

I'm looking for some clever trick to make the kernel treat a port as if I have it open, even without a living PID.  Something like NS FDs (https://lwn.net/Articles/407495/).

I know it's a stretch, but I am grasping, trying to avoid a process-based solution.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I have programmatic port forwarding, which happens through iptables.  I don't want to later bind() and accept on a port that can never reach me because it is forwarded.  The existence of the iptables `--dport 8000` happens early, but my (errant) process doesn't know about that.  And in fact, the mechanism may change from iptables.